# Why does the compiler throw an error saying overloaded constructor is ambiguous?

Tags: c++

The Example class is shown below:

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example(): x_(0) {}    // problematic constructor
    Example(int x = 1): x_(x){}    // not problematic constructor

    int getX() { return x_; }
private:
    int x_;
};
```

Testing out Example in main:

```
int main()
{
    // problem with this constructor
    Example example1;
    auto x1 = example1.getX();

    // no problem with this constructor
    Example example2(500);
    auto x2 = example2.getX();
}
```

**Issue Solved:**

Eliminate constructor ambiguity by removing the default parameter values in the 2nd constructor. The constructors would look as follows:

```
    Example(): x_(0) {}    
    Example(int x): x_(x){}
```

This would not violate the rules of cpp constructor overloading that lead to ambiguity.

Comment: Do things improve if you change the second line to `Shooter shooter1(500, 700, up);` ?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it's still the same

Comment: @IronProgrammer Provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the error.

Comment: I think you'll need to post enough code that people can compile it locally; as it is, there is no way for anyone to test for themselves.

Comment: or at least show us the 'Shooter' class

Comment: Why not use braces to avoid the possibility of a [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)? I.e. `Shooter shooter1{500, 700, up};`

Comment: The problematic line should be: `Shooter shooter1(500, 700, up);`  // **no more problem**

Comment: Wherever you saw an example of code that passes types and parameter names when creating an object, you should stay far away from there.

Comment: On something similar I did, I am getting this error: `call of overloaded ‘Shooter()’ is ambiguous
  Shooter shooter;` and this error: `error: request for member ‘getSprite’ in ‘shooter1’, which is of non-class type ‘Shooter(int, int`.

Comment: So maybe you missed that you have more than 1 error

Comment: Since nobody has said so explicitly: you have two constructors that can be used without arguments, which is ambiguous, and your second declaration declares a function. There is a list of good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @IronProgrammer The second error is a direct consequence of the first error (compiler think that you have declared a function `sprite1`). If you correct that, you will get an ambiguity since you will have 2 possibles constructors with no argument. Probably the best solution would be to remove the parameter less constructor. Alternatively, if it make more sense, you can remove default value for `x`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I removed the default constructor and it worked, however I don't see why it would be ambiguous as there wasn't a problem with the constructor overloading.

Comment: overloading and calling overloaded functions are different things. You may define two unequal functions, but then you can form a call that cannot be resolved in favor of either of them (e.g. because both can be used with same amount of implicit type casts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value for argument makes call to default constructor ambiguous. Which function this would call, the first constructor, or the second one?

```
    Example example1 = Example(); // equivalent of Example example1;
```

Only solution is not to form such declarations. Constructor with all arguments defaulted is equal to constructor with no arguments.

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example(int x = 0): x_(x){}    // same as default constructor

    int getX() { return x_; }
private:
    int x_;
};
```